# Sorting a list with an incomplete comparison function

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a set of objects, and I need to produce a sorted list, but my comparison function is incomplete and leaves some room for "imagination" on the part of the sorting algorithm.

Specifically, given a collection of trees like the following:

```
  A      E
  |      |
  B--C   F
  |
  D
```

What I have on hand is the set of nodes `{A, B, C, D, E, F}`, in no particular order, and a function to test direct parent-child relationships:

```
parent(A, B)
parent(A, C)
parent(B, D)
parent(E, F)
```

I need to flatten this into a list where parents come before their children, but other than that, the order is unimportant. So any of these results would be acceptable:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F.

A, B, D, C, E, F.

E, F, A, B, C, D.

A, E, B, C, F, D.
```

The set will be small, a few dozen at most, so I'm not too concerned about performance. What I am concerned about is avoiding temporary data structures other than lists: due to limitations of the language I'm using, organizing these items into a temporary tree (for example) would be unpleasant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this simple algorithm:

```
while unsorted set is not empty {
    elem = get element from unsorted set
    while elem has parent and parent is in unsorted set {
        elem = parent of elem
    }
    add elem to result list
    remove elem from unsorted set
}
```

Comment: +1 for an algorithm with no global/shared state: the language I'm using happens to pass lists by value (copying). And I actually do have a cheap operation to find the parent of an element.

Comment: Or maybe I don't... that operation might find a parent that isn't in the input set (I'm only considering a subset of a larger forest), so I have to search the input set anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) algorithm.

Here's the relevant algorithm from the Wikipedia article:

```
L ← Empty list that will contain the sorted nodes
S ← Set of all nodes

function visit(node n)
    if n has not been visited yet then
        mark n as visited
        for each node m with an edge from n to m do
            visit(m)
        add n to L

for each node n in S do
    visit(n)
```

Comment: The depth-first-search algorithm given on that page will be slowish, since it requires that you find a list of all parents of a given node (which in this case will require checking them all).  On the other hand, you won't need any intermediate data structures at all--just recursive function calls--unless you need to be able to detect cycles.

Comment: @Jason: AFAICT you only need the list of the node's children, not its parent(s).

Comment: +1 for the topological sort article. I knew this algorithm had to be in common use for something.

Comment: Oh, I see now. The OP doesn't have a way to enumerate the node's children, only a parent(X,Y) relation.